# Adding object in javascript array at runtime

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

The mRegion object adds last object multiple times, however the objBeacon prints different objects. What is wrong with the mRegion?

```
      var mRegion = new Array();

      var objBeacon = {
          id: '10',
name:'name',   
          description: 'description'
      };
      $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
                  // populate beacon registry in an array
                  for (var i in response.items[0].devices) {
                      objBeacon.id = response.items[0].devices[i].id;
                      objBeacon.name = response.items[0].devices[i].name;
                      objBeacon.description = response.items[0].devices[i].description;


                      console.log("value of i is" + i);
                      console.log(objBeacon);

                      mRegion.push(objBeacon);
                  }
                  console.log(mRegion);
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: There is no error, however the same object is being added in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in javascript are passed by reference. You only have one variable `objBeacon` and each array element is pointing to this variable. Whenever you change `objBeacon`, all references will change.

```
var mRegion = [];

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
  // populate beacon registry in an array
  for (var i in response.items[0].devices) {
    mRegion.push({
      id: response.items[0].devices[i].id,
      uid: '00',
      major: 1,
      minor: 1,
      name: response.items[0].devices[i].name,
      description: response.items[0].devices[i].description
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: will it make a difference if we use var mRegion = new Array(); instead of  var mRegion = [];

Comment: No, but the array constructor has some quirks with how it handles input parameters. That's why it is highly recommended to always use array literal `[]` when creating new arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You only ever create one object and assign a reference to it to `objBeacon`.

Each time you go around the loop you modify the single object you have and push an additional reference to it into the array.

If you want an array of different objects, you need to create a new object each time you go around the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using objects your using "references" instead of "clones".

That code should work (even it is not very beautifull)

```
var mRegion = new Array();


$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    // populate beacon registry in an array
    for (var i in response.items[0].devices) {
        var objBeacon = {
            id: '10',
            uid: '00',
            major: 1,
            minor: 1,
            name: 'name',
            description: 'description'
        };

        objBeacon.id = response.items[0].devices[i].id;
        objBeacon.name = response.items[0].devices[i].name;
        objBeacon.description = response.items[0].devices[i].description;


        console.log("value of i is" + i);
        console.log(objBeacon);

        mRegion.push(objBeacon);
    }
    console.log(mRegion);
});
```